# How to log in in an acceptance test without actually navigating to the login page and entering your credentials?

Tags: php, yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

In functional tests for Yii2, there is a method `amLoggedInAs($user)`

```
$I->amLoggedInAs(
    User::find()->where('id = 1')->one()
);
```

But for acceptance tests, there is no such method. Most of my tests require the user to be logged in, and the only way I see to log in is to programmatically navigate to the login page and enter your credentials, which is going to be quite time consuming if repeated for every test.

How can I log in during an acceptance test without going to the login page? Actually, I would expect to see `amLoggedInAs($user)` in `AcceptanceTester` as well as in `FunctionalTester`.

Comment: Why it is not fine to use login page?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas It takes some extra time to log in by submitting a login form. I would expect to see a default way to just set the required cookies to be logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.

Logging in usually uses session variables and you can't access them in acceptance tests.
If you could get access to restricted pages without actually logging in, it would be a major security hole in your website, so it is a good thing that you can't.

Comment: This is the right answer. However, you can improve speed of logging in by saving current session and reusing it for other tests. See http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#Session-Snapshot

Answer (score 0):

What do you need is to execute the login during acceptance test and then execute yout functions.

Here is the best answer to your problem: https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69572-acceptance-test-reuse-login-code/